# Sum the total values of count

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, multiple-columns

I know how to `count` or take `sum` but my question is different.

[image]

Above is my count list. I want to add up my  all 3 column counts like `7+68+13....= sum`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT od.`meter_serial`) AS 'OGP Created', 
COUNT(DISTINCT mp.`meter_id`) AS 'Installed & Un-Verified Meters', 
COUNT(DISTINCT ins.`meter_msn`) AS 'Installed & Verified', 
sd.`sub_div_code` AS 'SD Code',sd.`name` AS 'SD-Name'
FROM `ogp_detail` od
INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON od.`sub_div` = sd.`sub_div_code`
LEFT JOIN `meter_ping` mp ON od.`meter_id` = mp.`meter_id`
LEFT JOIN `installations` ins ON od.`meter_serial` = ins.`meter_msn`
WHERE od.`meter_type` = '3-Phase'
GROUP BY sd.`name`
```

I want the sum of counts to be shown below each of the `3` columns while displaying count as-well.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You want a fourth column showing the sum of the other three?

Comment: yes exactly i want to do it

Comment: "I want the sum of counts to be shown below each of the 3 columns while displaying count as-well." checkout GROUP BY 's modifer `WITH ROLLUP` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: It would be better if you added sample data as text to your question together with desired output. And you might just want to add with rollup to your group by statement to get column totals.

Comment: Side note: You are using GROUP BY in a invalid way.. SELECT ... sd.sub_div_code AS 'SD Code',sd.`name` AS 'SD-Name' ... GROUP BY sd.name, od.meter_type` is invalid SQL...  https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: It didn't give me any error but yes I have removed it

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either simply add the expression

```
COUNT(DISTINCT od.meter_serial) + 
COUNT(DISTINCT mp.meter_id) + 
COUNT(DISTINCT ins.meter_msn) AS total
```

Or make your query a subquery:

```
select
  "OGP Created", 
  "Installed & Un-Verified Meters",
  "Installed & Verified",
  "OGP Created" + "Installed & Un-Verified Meters" + "Installed & Verified" as total
from ( your query here ) q;
```

Comment: using sub-query giving me `Every derived table must have its own alias` error

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that. Solution: give the derived table (aka the subquery) an alias name. I've updated my answer.